# Has android KTX been deprecated completely or only some parts or extensions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ktx

After reading the announcement that android KTX is now deprecated, I have been reading about the alternatives and find a confusing point.

Have all KTX modules been deprecated or only some of them such as synthetic, serialized, etc?

```
sharedPreferences.edit {
    putBoolean("key", value)
}
```

Or the way of working with collections?

I enter the official KTX documentation and see no deprecation notice.

I give an example, has the way of writing sharedpreferences been deprecated with KTX?

I would be very grateful for a confirmation of all this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kotlin Android Extensions compiler plugin will be [deprecated](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.4.20?utm_source=android_broadcast_te&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=kotlin-vyshel-kotlin) not the Android KTX. More information you can get [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html).

Comment: Although the KTX plugin is deprecated, they pulled the Parcelize component out of it into a new plugin.